# How to copy a LINUX file using c# remotely?

Tags: c#, linux, copy

I have to make a duplicate  copy of a file located on a Linux Server and then rename that with another name. For example there is existing file in /temp/100.txt . I have to copy that file to same location with another name i.e. /temp/101.txt . How can I achieve that with c#.

We have that folder /temp available as NFS folder from IIS webserver on win 2003. Does c# library File.copy works on NFS file system ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, File.copy can work on NFS or any other filesystem you can mount R/W (if said FS is a destination -- even just R/O if it's only the source) on your Windows machine.  (SMB aka Samba is probably the most popular remote FS for Windows/Linux interoperability, but NFS has its own strengths).